# How do I compile PyQt5 on Windows without OpenGL?

Tags: windows, opengl, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to compile PyQt5 on a Windows installation lacking OpenGL (or so it seems), which breaks the build. I've configured PyQt as follows:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe .\configure.py -c -j 5 --no-qml-plugin --spec win32-g++ --confirm-license
```

Then the build (`mingw32-make`) breaks like this:

```
In file included from D:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:63:0,
             from D:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtGui/QOpenGLContext:1,
             from ..\qpy\QtGui/qpyopengl_api.h:31,
             from Q:\Users\arvek\Downloads\PyQt-gpl-5.2.1\sip/QtGui/qopenglshaderprogram.sip:333,
             from sipQtGuipart0.cpp:24:
D:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtGui/qopenglversionfunctions.h:785:43: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
 void (QOPENGLF_APIENTRYP MemoryBarrier)(GLbitfield barriers);
```

I'm guessing OpenGL is simply missing on this machine (a Citrix terminal) based on the compilation error. How do I configure PyQt not to try to include OpenGL support? I'm quite sure I managed to build PyQt5 for Python 2.7 on the same machine, avoiding the OpenGL problem, so there should be a way (but it eludes me at present).

Comment: no I think it is a compile error where GLbitfield isn't seen as an identifier

Comment: @ratchetfreak The reason being that OpenGL isn't installed?

Comment: no it means that an included header does something unexpected, if it wasn't installed you'd get a linker error or an error at run time. besides all windows comes with an opengl.dll in c:\system

Comment: @ratchetfreak I figured it might have to do with missing compile-time definitions; however, I've now tried building PyQt on a full Windows 8.1 installation, and it fails in the same way :(